# Send Email to user after click submit button

Tags: rules, emails, notifications

Currently I am doing a recruitment system using Drupal 7 where the applicant can apply the job and HR admin can shortlist the applicant.

I have created a "shortlist button" in the content type to let the HR admin change the applicant status from pending (by default) to shortlisted. I put some rules to change the user status.

So my question is: How can I send the email to notify the user after the HR admin clicks the "shortlist button" to inform the user that they has been shortlisted?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Workbench email](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_email) module.

> Provides a way for administrators to define email transitions and
>   configurable email subject / messages between those transitions. **Email
>   transitions can be defined as when content moves from state to state.**
>   Based on those email transitions, configurable emails can be created /
>   updated / deleted as the site admin see's fit.